# Error en using OfficeOpenXml

Tags: c#, epplus

Intento agregar esta referencia using a mi proyecto,

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
```

sin embargo me salta este error:

> CS0246: El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'OfficeOpenXml' no
> se encontró (¿falta una directiva o referencia de ensamblado?)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que necesitas una referencia para poder usar `OpenOfficeXml`, en este caso es `EPPlus`.

En tu proyecto abre "Manage NuGet Packages...":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instala `EPPlus`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma podrás construir tu proyecto sin problemas para usar `OfficeOpenXml`.

---

Recuerda también eliminar las directivas que se indiquen no sean necesarias.

Comment: @cosito que otros using relacionados a OfficeOpenXml tienes en tu clase. Veo que indica que la directiva no es necesaria!, probaste eliminandola?